# Django AbstractUser password is not hashing

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I've used as a model `AbstractUser` extended by custom fields, created form automatically by `ModelForm`. The problem is that, users except superuser cannot log in to system. I think it's reason, their passwords are not hashing. Where should I make it ? Here are my codes.

`forms.py`:

```
class CustomUserSignUpForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['username', 'password', 'user_image', 'role', 'branch', 'license_number', 'fin_number', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'patronymic', 'phone_number', 'email', 'voen_number', 'is_active']
```

`views.py`:

```
def sign_up(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserSignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = CustomUserSignUpForm()

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'sign_up.html', context)
```

`models.py`:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    patronymic = models.CharField(_('Ata adı'), max_length=150, blank=True)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    user_image = models.FileField(_('Profil şəkli'), upload_to='static/assets/images/user-images', blank=True)
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(_('Telefon'), max_length=20, blank=True)
    voen_number = models.CharField(_('VÖEN'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    fin_number = models.CharField(_('FİN'), max_length=20, blank=True)
    license_number = models.CharField(_('Lisenziya'), max_length=40, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define a function to hash that password, you must inherited save method for you user form

```
    class CustomUserSignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ............
    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(CustomUserSignUpForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: I've already tried this method. It has red line under ```super``` and self . Error is as follows: ```Bad first argument 'CustomUserSignUpForm' given to super()``` and ```Instance of 'Meta' has no 'cleaned_data' member```

Comment: I changed this methods place with ```Meta``` class, error has gone, but again password is not hashing

Comment: excuse me, try ```user = super().save(commit=False)```

Comment: Man, thank you sooo much ! you saved my life. I'm so sorry, but can you explain me the reason ? Why after deleting ```CustomUserSignUpForm, self```` it is worked ?

Comment: by ```user = super().save(commit=False)``` we inherited save method from ModelForm with argument commit=False, that not save instance right away, after it we call set_password method that hashed password, and after we call model save method for save it to the db

Answer (score 1):

This override of ModelForm is better off, because:
I check if the user exists.
I Hash de password if the password is not encoded.

```
class UsuarioAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
...

def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    try:
        user_database = USUARIO.objects.get(pk=obj.pk)
    except Exception:
        user_database = None
    if user_database is None \
            or not (check_password(form.data['password'], user_database.password)
                    or user_database.password == form.data['password']):
        obj.password = make_password(obj.password)
    else:
        obj.password = user_database.password
    super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Comment: Thank you bro, you save my day! Work like a charm! Add to import section: `from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password, make_password`